# Choosing half of prefix and suffix

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Consider two lists: $(1,2,\dots,n)$ and $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, where the second list is a permutation of the first. Does there exist a constant $c$ such that for any $n$ and for any second list, we can choose a subset $A\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of size at most $n/2+c$ so that for any prefix and suffix of either list of any length $k\in[1,n]$, at least $k/2$ of those elements are in $A$?

The $n/2$ part is necessary: even if we just have the list $(1,2,\dots,n)$ and require the condition on the prefix, when taking $k=n$ we already need to include at least $n/2$ elements. If we only want the prefixes and suffixes of the first list, we can choose $A=\{1,3,5,\dots\}$ along with $n$ (if not already included), which comes to at most $n/2+1$ elements.

Comment: Probably $n$ is even, can you add that in your question?

Comment: I see nothing against odd $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be reformulated as "Given a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, is it always possible to choose $a_j=\pm 1$ such that all partial sums $\sum_{j=1}^k a_j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^k a_{\sigma(j)}$ are bounded by some constant $C$". The answer is "Yes". Consider the graph in which the vertices are $1,\dots,n$ and edges are $1-2,3-4,5-6,\dots$ (white) and $\sigma(1)-\sigma(2), \sigma(3)-\sigma(4),\dots$ (yellow). If we manage to choose the signs so that every edge connects two vertices of different signs, we are done. However, the only chance to get a cycle in this graph is to alternate white and yellow edges, so all cycles are even, making our choice possible.

A more interesting question is what happens if instead of one, we have 5 permutations. I suspect the answer is still positive but, of course, this simple approach has to be modified to cover that case.

Comment: I don't see how we can only look at the partial sums of $\sum_j^n a_j$, and not $\sum_j^n a_{n-j}$ - the first seems like it would correspond to prefixes, the second would be postfixes perhaps? 
$$. $$
Likewise, such a $\pm 1$ labeling given by the graph doesn't directly give $A$ - as we can have $n$ labeled $-1$ with $1$ labeled $+1$ without consequence, yet this $A$ wont satisfy the claim.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl 1) Since the total sum is nearly 0, the tail is essentially minus the head. 2) We have no chance to label $n$ -1's and just one 1. *All* edges should join vertices of different signs and the white edges alone tell you that the number of 1's is about $n/2$.

Comment: 1) For any $C$, pick $n=3C$, with $\sigma = (1, 2, \cdots, 3C)$. Then the labeling: $-1, -1, \cdots, -1, 1, 1, \cdots, 1, 1, \cdots 1$ - ie, $C$ "$-1$"s followed by $2C$ "$1$"'s, causes problems. This has every prefix bounded between $-C$ and $C$, but has a suffix which violates that bound, (by double!) despite meeting the other criteria.
2) I feel like you've overspecified - Pick $n=4$, $\sigma = (1,2,4,3)$. Then the graph has edges: $1 - 2, 3-4$ (white), $1-2, 3-4$ (yellow), and the labeling $1, -1, -1, 1$ is a valid bipartition. But it does not give a valid $A$

Comment: @ArtimisFowl 1) Every prefix means every prefix up to the full size $n$; 2) $A$ is obtained by taking all integers labeled 1 and adding, say, 3 elements at the beginning and the end of each of the two sequences.

Comment: Confusion... Every prefix for that sting satisfies your constraint. Prefixes of the first 2c have sums in [-c, 0], and prefixes including at least the first 2c terms have sums in [0,c].

Comment: @ArtimisFowl Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. If you get general $C$, you should add $C+1$ extra elements from each side of each sequence to $A$ to offset a possible big disbalance. In my construction, $C=1$.

Comment: @fedja Please correct me if I'm wrong. Say numbers numbers assigned with $+1$ are from set $A$ in the original problem, $-1$ for others. With your proof, there could be a case where $1,3$ are $-$ and $2$ is $+$, which means prefix of length $3$ of list $1,2, \ldots$ has $1$ numbers from $A$. This contradicts to the condition that prefix of length $3$ must has at least $\frac 32>1$ elements from $A$. The original problem wrote $k/2$ instead of $\left \lfloor k/2 \right \rfloor$.

Comment: @ToanQuangPham As I said, the set A is a bit larger than the set of $+1$'s: you should also add a few (3 is more than enough) *extra* elements from both ends of both sequences exactly to compensate for the effect you mentioned.

Comment: @fedja  Regarding your question about the generalization to more permutations, I believe that Newman and Nikolov showed that the answer is negative.  See https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/alantha-newman-and-alexandar-nikolov-disprove-becks-3-permutations-conjecture/

Comment: @RaviBoppana Thanks. So, the trivial $\log n$ upper bound is the best possible :o. That's amazing, I would never think so (though believe it or not, yesterday I spent a few hours thinking exactly of the permutations described in the paper you quoted though I didn't manage to come to any conclusion about them).