# Choosing half of prefix and suffix for three lists

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Consider three lists: $(1,2,\dots,n)$, $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, and $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$, where the second and third lists are permutations of the first.
>
> Does there exist a constant $c$ such that for any $n$ and for any second and third lists, we can choose a subset $A\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of size at most $n/2+c$ so that for any prefix and suffix of any list of any length $k\in[1,n]$, at least $k/2$ of those elements are in $A$?

When there are only two lists, this is true as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256846/choosing-half-of-prefix-and-suffix), even with $c=2$. However, it seems unlikely that the coloring technique used in the solution can be applied here.

Comment: The work there actually requires at least $c=2$ - it's required for the list $(3,1,2,4)$, and is hidden when the reduction reduces to just prefixes.

Comment: I've fixed this.

Comment: I can prove bound $3n/4 + c$ if needed.

Comment: @Smylic That's not very interesting. The "trivial" (=having $\ge 2$ natural proofs) bound is $\frac n2+C\log n$ where $C$ depends on the number of sequences. Even random choice already results in $\frac n2+C\sqrt n$. The game is to bring the deviation from $\frac n2$ down to a constant (or to show that it is impossible in general).

Comment: @fedja What is the proof for your "trivial" bound?

Comment: @pi66 Which one do you prefer to see: the one a la Dirichlet, or the one a la Steinitz (the second one gives a slightly better constant in front of the logarithm, but the first one is a bit easier to write down and to comprehend). Both seem to be dead ends as far as the constant bound is concerned, so I'm not really sure whether it would be beneficial or counterproductive to post them...

Comment: @fedja Let's do the easier one. I think it would be beneficial given that it's only $\log n$ away.

Comment: @pi66 Posted. Unfortunately, as I said, it looks like a dead end. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Dirichlet proof of the $C\log n$ bound. I'll do it for 3 lists, though it works for any number of them. Again, this post is to set the level of "triviality", not to solve the problem.

I'll be thinking of the $\pm$ reformulation. Split each of 3 lists into groups of $k$ (say, $k=10000$) subsequent positions. Consider all possible combinations of $0,1$ of length $n$ and for each such combination compute the sum in each group. Since there are $2^n$ combinations and only $(k+1)^{3n/k}\le 2^{n/2}$ possible sum values, there are at least $2^{n/2}$ combinations with certain particular sums. Among them there are $2$ combinations differing in at least $0.01n$ positions (again just by the sheer count: the number of combinations differing from a given one in fewer than $0.01n$ positions is well below $2^{n/2}$). Subtracting, we get a sequence of $\pm 1$ *and* $0$ with every group of $k$ summing to $0$ and, therefore, all partial sums bounded by $k$. The problem is that we still have $0$'s. However they are at most $0.99n$ and we can start the argument all over looking only at the corresponding positions. If $C(n)$ is the best bound one can achieve for lists of length $n$, this gives the recursion $C(n)\le k+C(0.99n)$, whose solution is logarithmic in $n$.

**Edit** Pi66 asked me to add the Steinitz type proof, so here goes. Once you generalize it properly, it becomes even easier than the Dirichlet one (my original version was more complicated).

Let us generalize immediately and request that each $\varepsilon_j$ should be one of the endpoints of an interval $I_j$ of length $1$ containing $0$. Again, split the series into groups of $6$. Set all $\epsilon_j=0$ to start with. Now keep the sums over all groups $0$. That is $3\frac n6=\frac n2$ equations. So, as long as we have at least $\frac n2+1$ free variables, we can find a non-trivial solution of the corresponding system and add it with some coefficient to bring one more variable to an endpoint  of the corresponding interval. Thus, we can get $n/2$ of them where they should be. Now freeze those and look at what we need to do with the rest. The admissible intervals for them have shifted, but otherwise we have the same problem we started with only with $n/2$ numbers. This yields the recursion $C(n)\le 6+C(n/2)$. The rest is just the same as before.

**Final edit** Ravi Boppana attracted my attention to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2922), which shows that the trivial $\log n$ bound is, actually, the best possible. Quite amazing, isn't it?

Comment: When you do the recursion, how do you incorporate the solution of the recursion (i.e. positions that we need to change from $0$ to $\pm 1$) to the original solution (i.e. positions that are $\pm 1$ in the first level of recursion)? It seems that if you incorporate them directly, then the guarantee that all partial sums are bounded by $k$ might no longer hold.

Comment: @pi66 Exactly. They are bounded by $k$ (the partial sums over initial non-zeroes) **plus** the bound for the partial sums over the $\pm 1$ replacing zeroes ($C(0.99n)$). That's the whole problem.

Comment: Makes sense. If we change the problem from $\pm 1$ (in your reformulation) to $+2$ and $-1$, do you think a similar result still holds? That is, can we still make the partial sums bounded by $C\log n$?

Comment: @pi66 Yes. This proof fails but the other one survives. However, I firmly believe that the right bound should be constant. I'm just too stupid to see why :-(

Comment: Interesting, could you post the other proof too?

Comment: @pi66 OK, I'll try to do it later today.

Comment: @pi66 Done. $\phantom{m}$

Comment: Thanks - I'm really confused with your new proof though. What do you mean by "an interval $I_j$ of length $1$ containing $0$"? Doesn't an interval of length $1$ just contain $1$ number? The variables in the $n/2$ equations are all disjoint, so I'm not sure why you say as long as we have at least $n/2+1$ free variables, we can find a non-trivial solution of the corresponding system

Comment: @pi66   It is an interval of reals. The variables are not disjoint: each variable can occur 3 times (once in each list partition)

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is $\epsilon_j$? In your first solution, you split each list into groups of $k$ positions (so each list contains $n/k$ groups). Are you doing the same thing here with $k=6$, or are you doing something different? Also what is an interval $I_j$? Does it consist of the $\epsilon_j$'s?

Comment: @pi66 The same. No, $I_j$ is the interval whose endpoints are admissible values of $\varepsilon_j$ ($[-1,1]$ for all $j$ in the original formulation).

Comment: I see. In "add it with some coefficient to bring one more variable to an endpoint of the corresponding interval", what do you mean by "coefficient" here? Also, in the generalization where we want $\epsilon_j$ to be one of the endpoints of an interval $I_j$, if the endpoints are, say, irrational, then we can't get the sum of each group of $6$ numbers to be $0$, right?

Comment: @pi66 You have a non-trivial solution, so you can multiply it by any real number to get another one. Also we keep our $\varepsilon_j$ within the intervals but at each step we do not guarantee that they are at the endpoints. If the endpoints are bad, like you said, then it would merely mean that after the first step, within each group of length 6, there is an $\varepsilon_j$ that is not an endpoint yet but the sum is exactly $0$ nevertheless. Of course, we relax the control afterwards, so in the end, indeed, there may be no sums that are exactly $0$.

Comment: But if we multiply the solution, we would also need to multiply some $\epsilon_j$ that we have already fixed to be at an interval endpoint, no? Also, how do we relax the control afterwards? In the end, don't we want all $\epsilon_j$ to be at an endpoint of its interval? (Like in the original version, all $\epsilon_j=\pm 1$, *not* something in between)

Comment: @pi66 No. The "free" variables are those that aren't at the endpoints yet. So we want to move them but without violating the equations. I know, it may be pretty confusing if you haven't seen such tricks before and I am not terribly good at explaining things. What I can suggest, however, is a nice paper by Barany: http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/steinitz.pdf  where this machinery is carefully explained. Try to look at it and see if things get clear after that.